# Sheet metal behind drywall...why?

Tags: carpentry, remodeling

I’m trying to install a niche by my bathtub. when i cut into the drywall which is on an exterior wall there was a full sheet of metal behind the dry wall. it runs the length 60 inches and height 6 feet of the wall stopping right below the window. what is there sheet metal back there and can i cut

Comment: Have you looked to see if there are any electrical or utilities mounted to the exterior side of that wall Or vent stacks that come out of the ceiling just above it.

Comment: Probably just old-school water control.

Comment: Is the metal corrugated?